# How to disable "Insert" Command in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need a macro to disable inserting cells, rows and columns. I have tried these unsuccessful tricks (among others):

```
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Enabled = False

ActiveSheet.Protect AllowInsertingRows:=False, AllowInsertingColumns:=False

Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").FindControl _
 (ID:=296, Recursive:=True).Enabled = False

CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(, 21437).Enabled = False
```

In each trial I have retrieved errors or just achieved disabling the row's inserting when selecting a column and vice versa.
How can I get my goal?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to accomplish this by protecting your sheet with the right parameters,

try putting the below code in the object module for your worksheet (on the sheet tab in Excel, right-click and select *View code*):

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object) 

     'ProtectSheet
    ActiveSheet.Protect AllowInsertingColumns:=False, AllowInsertingRows:=False, UserInterfaceOnly:=True         
End Sub
```

UPDATE: you can also do or undo this in Excel with menu **TOOLS>>PROTECTION>>PROTECT SHEET** or on the ribbon the button is in the *Review* tab.

EDIT: for how to disable specific menu commands and controls please see [Excel MVP Ron de Bruin - Disable menus & controls](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win011.htm)

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is to disable the inserting rows option using the menu, so what I really want the macro to do is **not allowing the user to insert a row using the command bars**. I need to force the user to insert rows using a button with a macro in it. So, if I protect the Sheet, it is impossible to insert rows.

Comment: Your code can unprotect, insert and reprotect, or you could specify the `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` argument when protecting so that your code can still run.

Comment: @EvaFP: for how to disable specific menu commands and controls please see [Excel MVP Ron de Bruin - Disable menus & controls](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s4/win011.htm)

Comment: @EvaFP: try the new code with `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Now it works, but when I click on any button to run macros, the sheet becomes unprotected automatically...

Comment: yes you will need to re-protect the sheetusing that code at the end of your macro. You could put that code in a priocedure called 'Protect' then call it from the `sheetActivate` event as well as at the end of your macro.

Comment: Thanks again! It's working little by little, but now I have another problem... When a row is inserted through the macro, I add a dropdown list in some cells, I have already enable the option 'AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True' but I doesn't paste the value of the validation list :(

Comment: @EvaFP: I think for those cells it might be worth unlocking them in the Cell Format properties dialog (on the *Protection* tab)